# Default value of NSFileProtectionKey

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, data-protection

What is the default value of the attribute `NSFileProtectionKey`?

There are four possible values, but which one is the default one?

```
NSFileProtectionNone
NSFileProtectionComplete
NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen
NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication
```

I did not find the answer in the [NSFileManager iOS reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFileProtectionKey).

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155789/implementing-and-testing-ios-data-protection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the default value is `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide the reference:

https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

> **Protected Until First User Authentication**
>
> (NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication): This class
>   behaves in the same way as Complete Protection, except that the
>   decrypted class key is not removed from memory when the device is
>   locked. The protection in this class has similar properties to desktop
>   full-volume encryption,   and protects data from attacks that involve
>   a reboot. **This is the default class for   all third-party app data** not
>   otherwise assigned to a Data Protection class.

...

> **Data Protection in apps**
>
> The iOS Software Development Kit (SDK) offers
>   a full suite of APIs that make it easy for third-party and in-house
>   developers to adopt Data Protection and help ensure the highest level
>   of protection in their apps. Data Protection is available for file and
>   database APIs, including NSFileManager, CoreData, NSData, and SQLite.
>
> ...
>
> User-installed apps that do not opt-in to a specific Data Protection
>   class receive **Protected Until First User Authentication by default**.